# How to run parallel Test case in Selenium + TestNG

Tags: selenium, grid, webdriver, selenium-rc, testng

I have a test script as follows, what I need to know is how I can make it to run in different browser at same time but with different test data,

Exactly what I want is I want parallel instance of Test Case one in Firefox and other in Internet Explorer, but again I want to use different data for it

Eg:
-Firefox with 'username1'  and 'password1'

-Internet Explorer 'username2'  and 'password2'

it is like logging into GMAIL with different usernames and password parallel in different browser but not in sequence.

***Test Case :***

```
public class Gmail 
{
    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void search()
    {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
        element.sendKeys("username");
        WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.name("pass"));
        element2.sendKeys("password");
        element2.submit();
    }

    @Test
    public void compose()
    {
        driver.findElement(By.name("compose")).click();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void exit()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Please give your suggestion would help in my project.

Comment: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to do this:

1. Pass the required values as parameters in testNG.xml - in your case you need browserName, userName & password.
2. Create 2 separate "test" tag in testNG.xml with different userName & password parameter

   ```
      <test name="Test on FF">
       <parameter name="browserName" value="Firefox" />
       <parameter name="userName" value="user1" />
       <parameter name="password" value="pass1" />
      <classes>
         <class>name="Gmail"</class>
        </classes>
      </test>
      <test name="Test on IE">
       <parameter name="browserName" value="IE" />
       <parameter name="userName" value="user2" />
       <parameter name="password" value="pass2" />
        <classes>
         <class>name="Gmail"</class>
        </classes>
      </test>
   ```
3. Define "suite" tag as `<suite thread-count="2" name="Suite" parallel="tests">`
4. Access and use those in your @Test method by `@Parameters ({"browserName","userName","password"})` and instantiate corresponding driver

Comment: Thanks Surya, could you please brief if I am going to use huge set of iterations as the above XML would be difficult to manage.

Answer (score 0):

If you have huge set of data, you can externalize it.  Move it to an excel, yaml or whichever format you are comfortable with.  Use that as an input to your @DataProvider method.  In the @DataProvider, read all values from your chosen format and return.  In your testmethods specify the dataprovider method.  Read more about dataproviders [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders).   Give the excel sheet in your parameter values.  You can run the dataprovider parallelly by setting the 
parallel to true.  Make sure your driver instances are either Threadlocal values or are instantiated for each method else parallel runs may lead to failures.

Comment: Thanks a lot niharika_neo, I am trying it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with working code on http://www.ufthelp.com/2014/12/Parallel-execution-tests-in-testNG-eclipse.html

**XML File** will look like this

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
 <test name="Run in Firefox">
  <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"></parameter>
  <parameter name="userName" value="Test1"></parameter>
  <parameter name="Password" value="Pwd1"></parameter>
  <classes>
   <class name="srcTest.ParallelTesting"/>
  </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="Run in chrome">
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>
  <parameter name="userName" value="Test2"></parameter>
  <parameter name="Password" value="Pwd2"></parameter>
  <classes>
   <class name="srcTest.ParallelTesting"/>
  </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

**Java Code:**-

```
 @Test
 @Parameters({"userName","Password"})
 public void login(String userName,String Password){

   --Your Code--
 }

 @BeforeClass<br/>
 @Parameters({"browser"})
 public void BeforeClass(String browser) throws Exception {

  --Your code--

}
```